# RedBeanPhp fuse with CI 2.1.0 HMVC

Tags: redbean

the controller

```
class User extends MX_Controller{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
         $r=R::dispense('group');
         $r->GroupName="hh";
         $i=R::store($r);
         echo $i;
         $r->hello();
    }
}
```

the model

```
class Model_Group extends RedBean_SimpleModel{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct;
    }
    function open(){
        echo "model";
    }
    function update(){
        echo "update";
    }
    function hello() {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

the output
it just returns the id neither the hook functions (open -update -  etc........)nor the custom functions (hello) as mentioned from the redbean docs

so i am asking what's wrong or what i should do to work properly

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Redbean? Are you sure the Model_Group class is being included on a page?  I use Redbean and have this working with several of the tables.

Comment: ok my friend i used the one by rubensarrio at GitHub and it is the last 3 but still magic functions doesn't work at alleven if loading the model the magic functions doesn't work but it stores the value to the database and prints out the id

Comment: thanks a lot it worked \application\libraries\RB\drivers\ModelFormatter.php
in the function formatModel

replace the return with
return 'Model_'.$model;

and load the model through the controller:
$this->load->model('Model_item');

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, I think you should load a model to fix this problem.

For example:

```
 $this->load->model("module_name/model_name")
```